# Menu animation in Meteor

Tags: javascript, css, animation, meteor, reactjs

I'm trying to work with Meteor, React and FlowRouter.

I didn't work with animation in Meteor yet and I don't know where to start, but..

I am really impressed by the animation on [this site](http://Atmospherejs.com) (yeah, I don't only searching there hah :)

When we press to the menu icon then: all the current layout moves to the right and takes the half of the screen. on the left half of the screen me can see simple list menu. all this behavior happens really smoothly.

That is the question.
What technologies to use to make animation effects like that? Or may be you know how exactly  to make this effect?? Actually I want to find the way make something like this using Meteor and React. 
Very thank you for your answers!

**Update**

What do you know about Famo.us?

Comment: looks like bootstrap or foundation css animation. also look at uiHooks for Blaze; there may be similar components for React https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-ui-hooks

Comment: If you enjoy these animations, then you should definitely try Highcharts, sAlerts etc which makes your UI more responsive. refer to juliancwirko:s-alert-jelly, maazalik:highcharts. These are some simple and superb animations supporting meteor. Rest UI stuff animations can be achieved with Bootstrap-3 and CSS components.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but I am trying to find a way to animate big parts of my app. like example in my question, not notifications and etc. Do you know ways or technologies to do that?